# Reusing information from database in project

Tags: android, firebase

I'm looking for a tip to point me in right direction. I am working on an app that first downloads information from firebase (images and string data) and then uses the data across multiple fragments in a PageViewer. I wonder what kind of solution I can implement so that I download the data and update it in one place, both to save datatransfer and processing power. I was considering Android local database that uses miniSQL as well as just sending data in transactions between fragments, but I'm not sure It's the most efficient solution. I don't have any real experience in that field that's why I ask this question.

Comment: add splash Screen so you do all that it one place

Answer (score 0):

If it's small data with only strings you can keep that in the activity holding the viewPager and pass it to the fragment while intializing or by creating a method to get data from activity.

I suppose you are downloading multiple images first and then allowing users to interact. I would suggest downloading images asynchronously using Picasso or Glide later while allowing user interaction.

Other option -> You can write all the images as file in internal/external directory, create methods/ interface in activity to retrieve these images and pass it to the required fragments.

Comment: I was thinking about saving the images to internal directory, but what about database updates? Do you have an example of this implementation?